# cannot compare value with apostrophe using like in mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, database

By using **$quer1** am able to save value "Favorite's TV shows?" AS "Favorite\'s TV shows?"
 when i went into host's PHPMYADMIN and wrote a SQL 
query-

```
 SELECT ques_id FROM questions WHERE ques like 'Favorite\'s TV shows?'
```

It returns 0 rows yet 'Favorite\'s TV shows?' is in database

**$query2** returning error as it is not able to fetch any row, yet value exsist in database!!

```
$qques="q".$ques;
$query1 =sprintf("insert into questions(ques) values ('%s')",
mysql_real_escape_string($val));

$result = mysql_query($query1);
if (!$result) {
$message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
$message .= 'Whole query: ' . $query1;
die($message);
}

$query2 =sprintf("SELECT ques_id FROM questions WHERE ques like '%s'",
mysql_real_escape_string($val));
$result2 = mysql_query($query2);
if (!$result2) {
$message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
$message .= 'Whole query: ' . $query2;
die($message);
}else
{   $valueSecond= mysql_result($result2, 0);}
```

Comment: In SQL strings, you escape a single quote within single quotes by doubling it.

Comment: What does the data in your database look like? It might be mangled. Also, `mysql_query` is deprecated and should not be used in new applications, it will be removed from future versions of PHP. Is this a legacy application you're working on?

Comment: @FrankPl already used mysql_real_escape_string() to take care of it and it is saving in the database as Favorite\'s TV shows? I repeat!!

Comment: @dissectorz Is saving it as `Favorite\'s TV shows?` really what you want? I would want it saved in the database as `Favorite's TV shows?`!

Comment: @Fred-ii- stripslashes() will create a string as Favorite's TV shows? which again produces invalid query!!

Comment: @dissectorz Why is `\'` in your db to start with, doesn't that just cause problems to begin with? I'm confused.

Comment: The data in your database should be `Favorite's` without escaping. If there's a literal backslash in the database, then your data is mangled.

Comment: @FrankPl I would be glad if can produce an Answer where i can comfortable compare values with Favorite\'s TV shows? in dB

Comment: so we cannot compare if Favorite\'s TV shows? if '\' is in dB?

Comment: I Learn a lot here...thank u all...so what could be the right way to go with?

Comment: @dissectorz You need to tackle the problem at the "source" of input. Either using `strip_slashes()` or the built-in function. Least, that's what I think.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of escaping the apostrophe with a backslash, try it with a double apostrophe, like so:

```
select * from ABC where XYZ like 'Favorite''s TV shows?'
```

If the escaped apostrophe in in the database, you'll need to do this:

```
select * from ABC where XYZ like 'Favorite\\''s TV shows?'
```

Comment: Just use the escaping function provided by PHP. Do not do it by hand.

Comment: OP has used mysql_real_escape_string which does the correct escaping for you

Comment: in both the cases empty result!!

Comment: Don't break in and out of the quoted query string with double apostrophes, as has been said, use the built in stuff. It's been developed, tested, improved, tested and developed some more! using prepared statements would probably help you too